# reading pressed keys in Python 2.7 on windows 7 vs windows 10

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I'm a student and as part of a homework assignment, my partner and I built a small python program using Pyhook that reads each character that was pressed and then writes to file "The letter #letter# was pressed".

When we ran the program on my Windows 7 platform it operated just fine.
However, when we ran the program on his Windows 10 and later tested it on a university computer running Windows 8.1, we got blank spaces where the actual letters should go.

Is there any difference in interpreting the ASCII of letters between those windows platforms? (We know from googling this issue that Windows has made changes to its character map of pressing Alt + numbers but not for letters)

If not, is there any difference in how we write to file between those Windows platforms?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom

loc = 'c:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\test.txt'

def onkeyboardpress(event):
    if 64 < event.Ascii < 91:
        out = open(loc,'a')
        out.write('The letter ' + chr(event.Ascii) + ' was pressed\n')
        out.close()
    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = onkeyboardpress
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Thank you very much and have a great day!

**Edit 1:**

When I print the Ascii of the recorded event, it gives me 0 for all characters. That is why my file had nothing in it.
I'm guessing it something Unicode based or in fact, the Ascii did change.

I couldn't find the reason for it online so any suggestions on how to make it work for both platforms will be much appreciated!

Comment: pyhook calls its [`ConvertToASCII`](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/code/ci/master/tree/cpyHook.i#l271) function, which calls [`ToAscii`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646316). Attach a debugger and set a breakpoint on `ToAscii` to check the values being passed to it and its return value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply. As it turned out, in Windows 8.1 and 10, the Ascii value indeed gives 0. However, the Key Code value gives a different number for each pressed key which in the case of letters is identical to the Ascii.
I managed to use it instead and it worked out.